# Changing Layout type in XML file

Tags: magento2

[image]In `Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_category_view.xml` I tried to change it's layout from **2columns-left to 1column**.

I did override to by **1column** but overriding layout didn't show any effect to the structure. Can you please help me about this.

Thank You in advance.

Comment: Can you post the code for better view ?

Comment: bro can you help me about this?

Answer (score 0):

You have to just keep below code inside your theme layout folder,

Keep `layout=1column`

File path **`app/design/frontend/Vendor/themename/Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_category_view.xml`**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>      
    </body>
</page>
```

Comment: its already inside my theme layout folder.

Comment: you have to keep 1column not 1columns in your layout file

Comment: please update your code and check again.

Comment: updated to 1column. Again didn't work.

Comment: you have to keep only required code inside layout file, remove extra code from your file and remove var foldre, clear cache